# Is there a Javascript date picker that allows me to select multiple dates based on a weekday?

Tags: javascript, jquery, datepicker

I would like to able to select all Wednesdays in a given month by clicking on the day in the calendar UI. For example to schedule a meeting that occurs on every Wednesday. I would like the user to be able to just click on a day name rather than clicking every specific date.

I was wondering if anyone is aware of a Javascript date picker library that already has this feature or is this something I will have to write myself?

I've looked at a few multidate pickers available out there (http://multidatespickr.sourceforge.net/ for example) and they all have a feature to select a RANGE or the entire week however it seems that none of them support selection based on a specific week day.

Comment: might be easier with a calandar like http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/ WHat is use case?

Comment: @charlietfl The use case is that I'm allowing professors to track student attendance and to do that they need an interface to pick the dates that need to be tracked. Usually classes are on say Mondays and Fridays so I would like to allow them to click on Friday and select all Fridays in a given month.

Comment: fullcalendar has robust API...likely fairly easy to create what you need